# Using "terms" and "range" filters together in Elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I searched everywhere, but none of the answers met my requirements.
My code goes something like this:

File 1

```
<?php
 if($year != 0)
 {
 $temp = strval($year);
 $term =[ 
         "range" => [
           "decidedon" => [
               "gte" => $temp."-01-01",
               "lte" => $temp."-12-31"
                      ]
                    ]
        ];
 array_push($params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must'], $term);
 }
```

File 2

```
<?php
 $dummy = explode(" ",$cor);
 $params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must'] = ['terms'=> ['court' => $dummy]  ];
```

I include them in my index page at different instances, as follows

```
if(isset($_GET['cor'])){
 $cor = $_GET['cor'];
 if(strcasecmp($cor,"all")!=0){
  include 'courtfilter.php';  
  }
}

if(isset($_GET['year'])){
 $year = $_GET['year'];
 if($year != 0){
  include 'yearfilter.php';
  }
}
```

When I run a query, it says terms and range cannot be nested together.
Can someone tell me a better way to do this without complicating my program or without having to write a separate filter for these two?

*(I am a beginner, Please pardon me if I am wrong or if this is too trivial.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. In your second file, you need to insert the `terms` into your `must` like this:

```
$params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must'] = [['terms'=> ['court' => $dummy]  ]];
                                                                 ^                                 ^
                                                                 |                                 |
                                                               add this .....................and this
```

i.e. the `bool/must` must be an array and you were assigning it an object/hash directly.

A better way would be to initialize the `must` clause before including any of the files (i.e. before `if(isset($_GET['cor']))`). You would first initialize your `bool/must` array like this:

```
$params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must'] = [];
```

And then in both of your included files, you can simply do an `array_push()` like you do in the file `yearfilter.php`

Comment: Will try it and get back to you. Thanks.